# Power external op-amp using GPIO 5v and GND pin

Tags: gpio

Maybe a very simple question, is it safe to connect an external op-amps Vs+ and Vs- to the GPIO pins for 5V and GND respectively?

I have read shorting these pins may cause fuses to break in the Pi.

Will doing this work or should I use a separate power source to supply the op-amp?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 5V pins on the expansion header to provide power to external circuitry.

Indeed this is their purpose and it is safe (provided the power supply is adequate); an op-amp will require negligible power.

NOTE the 5V pins are **NOT** "GPIO pins"!

"shorting" ANY pins risks damage.